Scaling property of the Tricomi function
I know this is a simple question but I did not find the asnwer yet in any books about special function. I would like to know if it is possible to have a scaling property on the tricomi function, i.e. if it exists a formula that connects $U(a, b, cz)$ to some factors that depend on a, b, c and z times $U(a, b, z)$. Thank you for your patience.

I don't think so. Try specific cases $b=a+2$, then $b=a+3$...

Why those values? Does the tricomi function becomes something easier? I know that for $b = a+1$, the function becomes $U(a, a+1, z) = z^{-a}$ and this suggests that I may have a scaling property on z. Sorry, but I am not an expert of special functions. Thank you for your asnwer.

See DLMF. Replace $y\to(y-1)x$ in the addition formulae to obtain multiplication formulae.
